# Matlab: XLSWrite Cell Array with numeric and char

Tags: excel, matlab

I have a cell array with char-arrays in some, numeric values in other cells. I want to write the array to an excel sheet using xlswrite.

```
myCell{1} = cellstr('some string')
myCell{2} = 5

xlswrite(pathToWb, 'aSheet', myCell, 'A1')
```

does indeed write value 5 to range A2, but leaves A1 empty.

What am I doing wrong? I would also appreciate any help on cell-arrays in general...

Thanks!

Comment: I get errors from your code - can you please fix it so that it works? For instance, the last line gives the error "Sheet argument must be a string or whole number..."

Comment: Apologies, that last bracket in the first line wasn't supposed to be curvy

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution myself:

xlswrite cannot access a cell directly, instead addresses it like a normal array. Thus, using

```
myCell(:,:)
```

everything works as expected.

Thus, the line has to be

```
xlswrite(pathToWb, 'aSheet', myCell(:,:), 'A1')
```

---